# Dual booting, and lost rEFInd: how to recover OSX?

Tags: startup, unix, dual-boot, efi

I mostly followed [these instructions][1] for how to set up dual-booting on my macbook, and everything seemed fine, up to the very last step. Now when I reboot the system (even if I hold command-R) I don't get any rEFInd boot menu or recovery mode, it just boots to the Ubuntu partition and I have no way of booting into OSX, which means this is now just a single-boot option Ubuntu machine.
I suspect it may be because during the OSX partitioning, I created *two* partitions, and then consolidated them into one during the Ubuntu  installation phase.

What should I do from this point?

**Edit** solved: From within Ubuntu, install refind again from the secondary installation. In case of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install refind
```

Let the program install to the partition that it wants to install to, then reboot, and you should see the rEFInd menu again.

Comment: From Ubuntu enter the command `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` and post the output to your question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson. I've edited in the output you requested.

Comment: Apparently, the current release of El Capitan has a bug. When resizing the El Capitan partition, the Recovery partition needs to be moved. After testing in VirtualBox, I was able to determine that the Recovery partition is not being entirely copied to the new location. This is probably why you can not boot to Recovery mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have Ubuntu running, from within Ubuntu, install refind again from the secondary installation. In case of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install refind
```

Let the program install to the partition that it wants to install to, then reboot, and you should see the rEFInd menu again. Selecting OSX from that points worked as normal for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try going into recovery mode like [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and then follow [these](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) instructions..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I'm unable to access recovery mode at all. When I hold command-R down on start-up I don't get the refind menu, and I don't get Apple's menu either. No matter what I do, I still boot into the new Ubuntu system.